# Get Pycharm to see dynamically generated python modules

Tags: pycharm, airflow

Using Apache Airflow they install plugins by modifying `sys.modules` like this:

```
 sys.modules[operators_module.__name__] = operators_module
```

Which is how they get python classes from their `plugins` folder to be imported via

`from airflow.operators.plugin_name import Operator`

even though the class `Operator` exists inside

`airflow/plugins/Operators.py`

This makes it impossible for PyCharm to understand the above import statement because it is a non-traditional way of generating module/module name.

**Is there any way to get PyCharm to have something like a module/package alias for situations like these?**

Comment: Did you have any progress with this? I'm also struggling with PyCharm in this regard.

Comment: I did have some luck with symlinks, I think, but I can't remember for sure. Put a link in site-packages that points to your plugins folder, and the link needs to have the same structure as your import.

Comment: @Hexworks take a look at my answer with two imports. It works well for a single repository projects.

Answer (score 5):

If your plugin is in the same repository as the dag you can wrap you import in `try-except` block:

```
try:
   # local development
   from plugin_name import Operator
except ImportError:
   from airflow.operators.plugin_name import Operator

my_operator = Operator(...)
```

And mark `plugins` directory as sources in your PyCharm Project Structure.
Afterwards PyCharm picks up your plugin source code and works nicely with autocompletion and so on.

Comment: Well the way Airflow works is that `from plugin_name import MyOperator` actually works at runtime too since anything in the plugins folder is available. So chances are that the `from airflow.operators.plugin_name import MyOperator` never gets invoked and it doesn't matter either.
I think the plugin registration mechanism is more useful when importing plugins from a non airflow package but then we are back to square one when it comes to PyCharm.

Answer (score 4):

Airflow loads plugins by searching the plugins directory for `AirflowPlugin` subclasses, then binding the operators etc. stored in attributes of those subclasses to new modules under the `airflow` namespace.

Resolving code transforming classes into modules is beyond PyCharm's capabilities, so unless you want to override this behavior by adding the plugins directory to `sys.path` and importing the contents directly, the best solution is to whitelist the modules airflow creates through `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> Unresolved references` and adding `airflow.operators.plugin_name` to the `Ignore references` list. Then, using the module like so:

```
from airflow.operators import plugin_name
task = plugin_name.Operator()
```

will no longer raise any errors, although you still won't get the benefits of code completion.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I've found (which is not a very good solution) is to simply ignore all unresolved attributes in each DAG file. You can do this if you hover over the error, select "More actions..." and then "Mark all unresolved attributes of [DAG FILE NAME] as ignored." Screenshots below.

This is not a very good solution because it sort of defeats the purpose of an IDE, so I'm hoping eventually somebody who understands the issue better will think of a better solution and post it here :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other solutions exist but referencing @stephen answer you that can

```
simply ignore all unresolved attributes in each DAG file.
```

but I found that marking the **dags** directory as ***sources_root*** resolves the issue of unresolved attributes in an IDE (I am using specifically IntelliJ and Pycharm but could work for other IDEs as well)

[image]