# Airflow - Cannot import custom plugin

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I followed the [tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) about plugins.

I looked online also and find : [Can't import Airflow plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907813/cant-import-airflow-plugins)

But the top answer doesn't help me either.

Here a simplifed version of my project :

```
airflow_home
├── dags
│   └── etl.py  
└── plugins
    ├── __init__.py
    └── operators
        ├── __init__.py
        └── dump_file.py
```

plugins/operators/dump_file.py

```
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults

class DumpCsvFileToPostgres(BaseOperator):
    [...]
```

```
# plugins/__init__.py

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from plugins.operators.dump_file import DumpCsvFileToPostgres

# Defining the plugin class
class CustomPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "custom_plugin"
    operators = [
        DumpCsvFileToPostgres
    ]
    helpers = []
```

```
dags/etl.py

# tried 
# from airflow.operators import DumpCsvFileToPostgres
# from airflow.operators.custom_plugin import DumpCsvFileToPostgres
from custom_plugin import DumpCsvFileToPostgres

[...]
```

I still get

> Broken DAG: [/root/airflow/dags/etl_dag.py] No module named 'custom_plugin'

My webserver and scheduler are running with a docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  [...]

  webserver:
    image: godatadriven/airflow:latest
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://${POSTGRES_USER:-airflow}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-airflow}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-airflow}
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
      - WAIT_FOR=postgres:5432
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/root/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/root/airflow/plugins
      - ./logs:/root/airflow/logs
      - ./environment.yml:/dependencies/environment.yml
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: upgradedb_webserver

  scheduler:
    image: godatadriven/airflow:latest
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://${POSTGRES_USER:-airflow}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-airflow}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-airflow}
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
      - WAIT_FOR=webserver:8080
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/root/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/root/airflow/plugins
      - ./logs:/root/airflow/logs
      - ./environment.yml:/dependencies/environment.yml
      - ./dataset/Iowa_Liquor_Sales.csv:/root/airflow/dataset/dataset.csv
    command: scheduler
```

Comment: While I've never used `Airflow` `plugin`s, from the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html#interface), I infer that the *import statement* should be `from airflow.operators.custom_plugin import DumpCsvToPostgres`. If you look closely, your current import statement takes no account of your operator being exported as an Airflow plugin. Its a regular python import statement, where the top-level module is not available directly in `PYTHONPATH`; hence the error

Comment: That's why you can see those lines of code commented
# tried # from airflow.operators import DumpCsvFileToPostgres# from airflow.operators.custom_plugin import DumpCsvFileToPostgres

Comment: What is the value for `core__plugins_folder` in the airflow configuration?

Comment: In `dags/etl.py` , change `from custom_plugin import DumpCsvFileToPostgres` to `from plugins.operators.dump_file import DumpCsvFileToPostgres`

Comment: @nightgaunt the value is `plugins_folder = /root/airflow/plugins` and this is what I have pointed to my docker volumes 
`./plugins:/root/airflow/plugins`

Answer (score 1):

The import statement in your `etl.py` should be `from airflow.macros import custom_plugin`

Also, check that the value of `plugins_folder` key in `airflow.cfg` should point to `plugins` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Out of many solutions, One possible solution can be:

In `dags/etl.py` , change this line

```
from custom_plugin import DumpCsvFileToPostgres
```

to

```
from plugins.operators.dump_file import DumpCsvFileToPostgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you seen this stack-overflow? It seems that there is a much simpler way to import custom operators

[Can't import Airflow plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907813/cant-import-airflow-plugins)