# What is the correct way to use custom plugins (hooks, operators and sensors) in airflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, plugins, airflow

this is my first post asking for help with airflow. In my company we were using version 1.10.15 of Airflow with some custom modules saved in a customs folder inside the DAGs folder and everything worked fine, I'm upgrading to version 2.1.0, and because of that I want to follow good practices and turn that custom folder into custom plugins which Airflow treats by default. So far so good, what happens is that I can't find a clear documentation that works for the version I'm using (2.1.0), I always find documentations of past versions or that don't even mention the version but I couldn't make it work, I'll try put below how my environment is configured as well as an example of what I need.

My environment is set up like this:

```
dags
└── my_dag.py
plugins
├── __init__.py
├── hooks
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_hook.py
```

It is configured like this because I followed the instructions on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640550/14695916) and the [astronomer guide](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-importing-custom-hooks-operators). Before they ask the plugins_folder configuration in the airflow.cfg file is pointing to the correct folder.

Now let's have my questions:

1. Is it necessary to create folders inside the plugins folder separating hooks, operators and sensors?
2. is it necessary to have a `__init__.py` file in every folder inside plugins? I put the files in blank like the link I gave above, but without success, if that's what the content of the files would be? could you give me examples?
3. Is it necessary to execute the `airflow plugins` CLI command? I executed the command and the return is

```
airflow@ip:/opt/airflow$ airflow plugins
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/providers/http/operators/http.py:26 DeprecationWarning: This decorator is deprecated.

In previous versions, all subclasses of BaseOperator must use apply_default decorator for the`default_args` feature to work properly.

In current version, it is optional. The decorator is applied automatically using the metaclass.

No plugins loaded
```

4. is there any other way to do this natively and correctly?

Well to sum up I'm really lost, I apologize because besides not being fluent in English I'm studying python for just over 3 months, so basic things may be going unnoticed by me, I would be very grateful if someone could give me a light with some code examples, if you need more details on how I'm doing the codes I'm ready to give you all the details, thanks and I'm waiting

[update]

After a lot of trying and researching, I finally figured out how to get plug-ins recognized, followed the [Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/configuring-dag-import-plugins.html) and everything workeds well. In short, you need to follow the folder structure with an **init**.py file in each folder and the central point is the my_airflow_plugin.py file which points to each custom plugin. Well, at least it was registered for those who have the same doubts in the future.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It too broad a question and it will be hard to answer it without adding somebody's own opinion. Also, I don't understand the main problem you wanted to solve, the actions you've tried, and the errors you've got.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the central point here is that Airflow, at least as far as I understand, gives the possibility to turn a python script into a "native" plugin, if I use my code inside the Dags folder it is executed with success, however I would like to follow the best practices and use it as a native plugin, the central question is what are the necessary steps to achieve this

Comment: @AgailSanchez, please add your update as an answer.