# Import error in VSCode despite setting the PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, airflow, pythonpath

I have an airflow environment locally deployed on WSL, and I am using VScode to debug and code.

My app folder structure is as follows:

```
~/workspaces
|--- .env
|---organization/gcp/datalake
    |--- dags
        |--- //My dags
    |--- plugins
        |--- __init.py__
        |--- operators
            |--- __init.py__
            |--- facebook_operators.py
        |--- hooks
            |--- __init.py__
            |--- facebook_hooks.py
```

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of VSCode regarding the imports.

I added the `dags` and `plugins` folders to the `PYTHONPATH` via `.env` file. My VSCode is opened directly on the `workspaces` directory.

The problem :

I get import errors, although I can successfully `go to definition` of the class I want to import.

Example : In my `facebook_operators.py`

`from hooks.facebook_hooks import FacebookAdsHook`
raises the following error :

> No name 'facebook_hooks' in module 'hooks'

The contents of my `.env` file:

```
PROJECTDIR=~/workspaces/organization/gcp/datalake
PYTHONPATH=${PROJECTDIR}/plugins
PYTHONPATH=${PROJECTDIR}/dags:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Where did I go wrong? I'd like to understand and solve this error please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` to your `.vsode/settings.json` file like so:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./airflow/plugins"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement at the beginning of the file "`facebook_operators.py`" to help VSCode find the file that needs to be imported:

> ```
> import os,sys 
> sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
> ```

(VSCode defaults to find the file from the parent folder of the currently opened file. We can use the above statement to add the file path that needs to be imported to the system path, and then VSCode can find it.)

[image]